# Xslt 1.0 to convert date to dateTime format

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I am new to xslt. so this might be a basic question. I am trying to convert a date received in xs:date format to xs:dateTime
input received is :
`<tns:receivedDate>2017-06-27</tns:receivedDate>`
I want to transform it to `2017-06-27T00:00:00.000-05:00` or `2017-06-27T00:00:00.000`

i tried the statement below but doesnt work

```
<tns:receivedDate>xs:date(<xsl:value-of select="//ns0:receivedDate"/>)cast as xs:dateTime</tns:receivedDate>
```

Please let me know what is missing. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT 1.0 has no concept of dates. You need to do this using string manipulation - for example:

```
<tns:receivedDate>
    <xsl:value-of select="//ns0:receivedDate"/>
    <xsl:text>T00:00:00.000</xsl:text>
</tns:receivedDate>
```

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 2.0+ you could just use

```
xs:dateTime(xs:date('2017-06-27'))
```

[Check it](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/0920da887804fc3ad4ada26edd97dadd).

But you have tagged this as XSLT 1.0, wich left you with just a string concatenation:

```
<tns:receivedDate>
     <xsl:value-of select="concat(//ns0:receivedDate,'T00:00:00.000')"/>
</tns:receivedDate>
```